# How to develop an iOS framework which includes image resources?

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, nsbundle, ios-frameworks

I am developing an iOS framework which includes image resources, I call the methods below in the framwork,

```
crossImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cross"];
arrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow"];
```

and then I build a demo to test my framework, but find crossImage and arrowImage are both nil; Afterwards, I figure out `imageNamed:`method
 will search images in the app's directory not in the framework's, so I can fix it by adding the two images to the demo project. However, it's barely elegant. so any other solutions to target the images in my framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, I create a bundle to hold all image resources, and we provide *.framework and *.bunlde, that's more elegant.

Comment: Can you be more clear on how you are providing those?  Sample code would be helpful.

Answer (score 23):

You can load the image from framework using:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name
               inBundle:(NSBundle *)bundle
compatibleWithTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)traitCollection
```

method.

In your framework class write like:

```
NSBundle *frameWorkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
UIImage *arrow = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow" inBundle:frameWorkBundle compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
UIImage *cross = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cross" inBundle:frameWorkBundle compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
```

Refer [UIImage Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:) for more info about this method.

Comment: The method you suggest only supports iOS 8.0 and later, what if on iOS 7.0 and 6.0?

Comment: @GaojinHsu: AFAIK in iOS 7 and 6.0 apple won't support creating custom frameworks. Use Static Library and custom bundle for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

You can also load images using:

```
[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

The path you'll want to generate from the bundle path. Something like:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[YourFramework class]];
NSString* path = [bundle pathForResource:@"cross.jpg" ofType:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work only when your images is NOT in `.xcasserts`.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourFramework.framework/imageName"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to load my images in a Swift framework by using

```swift
UIImage(named: name, in: Bundle.module, compatibleWith: nil)
```